# the building has emerged as architectural backdrop to

Tags: indefinite-article

This is from [a *Los Angeles Times* article](https://www.latimes.com/entertainment-arts/story/2022-02-28/how-volodymyr-zelenksy-uses-kyiv-gorodetsky-house-on-social-media?fbclid=IwAR16T2w3Ea3zdby5njyqZMBnbIKwoVpoS-QOwCqxqSfBaMRcOyC5SrpiwHQ).

> It therefore could not be more apropos that the building has emerged
> **as architectural backdrop** to one of Ukrainian President Volodymyr
> Zelensky’s urgent social media dispatches.

This is a sample of 'backdrop' in https://www.lexico.com/definition/backdrop

> ‘the conference took place against a backdrop of increasing diplomatic
> activity’

I think the phrase in bold should be 'as an architectural backdrop'.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right. But read enough [journalese](https://www.lexico.com/definition/journalese) and you almost stop noticing!

You *could* say "...as **an** architectural backdrop to..." but in this context it should probably be "...as **the** architectural backdrop to...": presumably, it's the *only* backdrop.

Perhaps it would be more succinct without the word "architectural". Aren't buildings *always* architectural?

> ...the building has emerged as the backdrop to...

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The lack of an article, definite or otherwise, is known as the "zero article".  The zero article is used for mass nouns (water), institutions (school), proper names (John), and abstract concepts (love).

You are correct that "as an architectural backdrop" would be a good sentence, however, that does not mean that the zero article is *necessarily wrong*.  It's a little odd to do so for everyday speech, but some people (and newspapers specifically) enjoy transforming concrete nouns into *abstract nouns* by using the zero article this way.  For newspapers, it provides a slightly *poetic* feeling to the writing, but also more importantly reduces the word count, enabling an editor to save space on the page.

So what does it mean to convert "an architectural backdrop" to become an abstract noun?  Don't think of it as a thing, exactly, but instead it would be the nebulous concept of "architectural backdrop" in general.

I am imagining a movie director saying something like, "We need architectural backdrop for this scene!"  And someone asks, "You mean a fancy building?"  "Just something, I don't care what!  Just make sure it's architectural!"  While in the planning stage, it isn't specific enough to even have the indefinite article, it's just a nebulous idea until you make it concrete by picking something.  Once you've picked something, it then becomes an object that needs an article.

Yes, this is a little strange... but it isn't wrong, just slightly poetic.

Comment: Thank you very much.